# Is it possible to use gdb to debug remotely over ssh?

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging

Can I debug a program running on a remote target to which I have ssh access, using local source files?

Say I've got a program called hello.c, in directory `/home/jla/hello` on my home machine.

And on the remote machine I put this same file in a directory /hello, and compile it with 
`$ gcc -g -o hello hello.c`, and then delete the remote hello.c, but leave the executable.

Can I then run gdb locally, get it to ssh in to the remote machine to run the executable, but use the local sources as reference?

Notes:

1. Annoyingly, the remote machine is very stripped down and can't be altered. It has gdb, but it doesn't have gdbserver
2. Note that the local and the remote machine have different architectures. In this particular case 64bit and 32bit intel
3. What I really want to do is run it under emacs/gud. But this would be a great start.

Comment: gdb and gdb are just a user-mode programs. You can't copy one or the other to the remote into your own directory? or /tmp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The architectures of remote and local machines matter very little. What matters is how `hello`, `gdb` and `gdbserver` are built.

It sounds from your description that `hello` is built (on remote machine) for `x86_64-linux-gnu`

That means you need `x86_64-linux-gnu` `gdbserver`, and also a 32-bit GDB that is capable of debugging `x86_64` binaries. You should be able to build both, copy `gdbserver` to the remote machine, and debug "normally".